# Nonlinear objective function with a single variable

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a nonlinear minimization model with a single variable as follows:

$$\min_{x \in [0,h]} \ z\left(x\right) := a \, x^b + c \, \left(h-x\right)^d$$

Besides, for the parameters, we have $0 \le b, d \le 1$ and $a, c > 0$. The first derivative is as

$$\frac{dz}{dx}=abx^{b-1}-cd{\left(h-x\right)}^{d-1}$$

and the second derivative is as

$$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}=ab\left(b-1\right)x^{b-2}+cd\left(d-1\right){\left(h-x\right)}^{d-2}$$

Perhaps we should investigate $\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}$. If it is negative (because $0 \le b, d \le 1$), there is no need to solve $\frac{dz}{dx}=0$, and we can conclude that the optimal answer is on one of the extreme values of $x$. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. The minimum of a function $z \in C^2([0,h];\mathbb{R})$ which is strictly concave (i.e. satisfies $z'' < 0$) is attained at one of the endpoints $x = 0$ or $x = h$. This is your case when $0 \leq b, d \leq 1$ (and at least one of them is not $0$ or $1$). When both $b$ and $d$ are $0$ or $1$, your function is affine so the conclusion stays the same (although the function is not strictly convex anymore).

This is the "mirror case" of the [classical question of whether the maximum of a convex function is attained at its endpoints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411313/convex-function-implies-max-at-endpoint-for-closed-interval-proof), which has already been answered here.

Comment: Thanks a million for your excellent explanation!